# Installation on a wiped computer

Tags: installation, laptop

I want to install ubuntu to an old Dell Latitude D630 that is completely wiped. It has no operating system on it. How can I install an operating system on it with out switching to ubuntu on my Windows Desktop? Every Download it seams as if it wants me to switch to ubuntu. I have a gateway with windows on it that I don't need ubuntu for. Is there a way I can get the operating system and put it on a flash drive and boot it on my old laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ummm I don't really know what trouble are you having but the mainstream way of installing Ubuntu is through windows!!

all you need is the Ubuntu iso and a program that makes the bootable usb from that iso.

here's the link for Ubuntu 13.10 32bit iso http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

if you want to install Ubuntu 12.04 then here it is http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts (32bits also)

You can ask me what's the difference between those two versions. Anyways I recommend 13.10

and here's the program that you'd use to make the usb stick (with a guide how to use the program) http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

...that's it! make the USB stick, plug it into the laptop and carry on! You can feed me back if you have any issues or questions ;)

...when you're done installing it I'd tell you about LXDE which is a lite user interface that you can install to ubuntu. It would make the laptop faster.

Comment: "... but the mainstream way of installing Ubuntu is through windows!!" It is? I've never installed any Linux through Windows.

Comment: ...well you have the right to say that I'm not very accurate but lately it's so popular that people switch from windows to Ubuntu; they're drawing lots of the community's attention. that's why I said so :)

Comment: The most common way of installing Ubuntu on a computer is by creating a live USB and booting from that. How the Ubuntu gets on the USB doesn't much matter. Windows, Mac and Linux all have simple ways do do this. unetbootin is the most common as there's a version for Windows, Mac and Linux.  `http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/'

Comment: okay,yes! true! -though some of these programs are not cross-platform-

Comment: unetbootin **is** cross-platform. It's also among the most common, most popular, and easiest ways write any Linux distribution to a USB drive. Personally, I prefer to download the correct .iso and use `dd if=inputfile.iso of=/sdb`, but that's *nix specific.